# using REG ADD in PowerShell to add registry key with double quotes

Tags: powershell, windows-registry

I am trying to add registry keys to Windows 10 using a PowerShell script. The key in the registry must have double quotes included in the data field so I understand I must escape the double quote with a backslash.

The following example command throws a syntax error when executed in Powershell but works perfectly in a Command prompt window:

```
REG ADD \\COMPUTER1\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcpm-notify /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files\Dell\CommandPowerManager\NotifyService.exe\"" /f
```

I have tried changing the escape characters to ` and using """ etc but I cannot get any combination to work in a PowerShell.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The following example command throws a syntax error" - If you want help provide your error.

Comment: Why don't you just use the shortname for Program Files instead of dealing with a space, although your underline problem, is your syntax is wrong.  You have unmatched escape characters "\" through your directory string.  You can also use `%ProgramFiles%` but resolve your directory problem first.

Comment: You can do something like `$ProgramFiles = "${Env:ProgramFiles}"` to make it simple

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The only error thrown is "Syntrax Error - check REG ADD /?"

Comment: Unfortunately this is a generic script to add double quotes to any unquoted paths with spaces. It's a security requirement. Not all will be Program files.

Comment: Have you confirmed you actually NEED to include those wrapping quotes?

Comment: @Techie007  yes afraid so.

Comment: Why not use single quotes around the text, so double quotes can be inserted normally? EG: 'my var with "quotes"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]` to add the key.

For example:

```
$RemoteReg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$TargetComp)
$NewKey = $RemoteReg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\")
$NewKey.CreateSubKey('dcpm-notify`)
$NewValue = $RemoteReg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcpm-notify")
$NewValue.SetValue('ImagePath', 'C:\Program Files\Dell\CommandPowerManager\NotifyService.exe')
```

Where `$TargetComp` is a computer you want to edit the registry for.

Please note that I have not tested the exact code, but I have used something very similar to this in the past and works without any issues. So run this on a test system first if anything.

Comment: ah, OK. So with this we could use the Powershell escape character ` to add double quotes to the value? I'll give that a try in the morning.

Comment: I managed to rewrite my scripts incorporating this method and it certainly go t me out of of a fix. Struggled getting it to work on remote registries but was able to overcome the need for that.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using PowerShell, I'd suggest using the `New-Item` and `New-ItemProperty` cmdlets instead of Reg.exe, as they will let you include the escaped quotes.

E.G:

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcpm-notify"
$name = "ImagePath"
$value = "`"C:\Program Files\Dell\CommandPowerManager\NotifyService.exe`""

# If registry path doesn't exist, create it.
If (-NOT (Test-Path $registryPath)) {
    New-Item $registryPath | Out-Null
}

New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath `
    -Name $name `
    -Value $value `
    -PropertyType ExpandString `
    -Force | Out-Null
```

Note: This example is targeted at the local machine. To run it against remote computer(s), look into using the [Invoke-Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) PowerShell cmdlet to invoke the above commands on the remote computer(s).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer would be to use single quotes around the text so double quotes become text by itself.

Your command would become:

```
REG ADD \\COMPUTER1\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcpm-notify /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d '"C:\Program Files\Dell\CommandPowerManager\NotifyService.exe"' /f
```

To explain it further:

Powershell knows two ways to work with text.

```
$test = "This is a test"
$test2 = 'This is also a test'
```

Because the above works, it allows you to do this:

```
$test3 = 'This is "double quoted" text'
$test4 = "This is 'single quoted' text"
```

And if you need to have a string which has both, you can accomplish it as follows:

```
$test5 = 'This is "double quoted" and ' + "'single quoted' text in one"
```

Comment: I had thought this originally too, but testing revealed that the inner quotes are still removed from the string before being added to the registry.  I think it has something to do with the way REG.exe handles the string.

Answer (score 0):

[Tested] For anyone that still wants to use reg add in powershell, just add ` after the backslash. The reg commands requires \" when you need to add double quotes in the value of an entry and powershell escapes double quotes by using `

When you run in powershell:

> REG ADD \COMPUTER1\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\dcpm-notify /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\`"C:\Program Files\Dell\CommandPowerManager\NotifyService.exe\`"" /f

The command will be rendered as the original.